# iOS Bubble Popup Menu similar to ITunes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Could anyone provide some guidance on how to implement that speech-bubble like popup menu when you click "More" in the IPhone IPod application toolbar?

Comment: Are you talking about what one sees when they click on "More..." in the iPhone's iTunes app (which appears to be a standard table view), or are you talking about something else? Maybe you could edit your question to include a screenshot?  Right now, your question is not clear to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`UIPopoverController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html). Popover controllers are just containers for view controllers: write a view controller that does what you want, and you're set. But this is for iPad. If you want this for iPhone, then read on. I have put up some solutions.

You could even explore `UIActionSheet` but `UIPopOverController` gives more flexibility.

I believe you are talking about something like this ?

[image]

Here are some solutions you could adopt -

1. Forgot that you wanted this for iPhone, Have a look at the iPhone `UIPopoverController` implementation: [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)
2. On iPhone you would generally use a `UIActionSheet` for a stack of buttons like that.  It slides up from the bottom, rather than popping up next to the button, but that's the standard behavior on iPhone.
3. Or you could manually instantiate a UIView using a custom background image or drawing with transparency, add some UIButtons (or other type of custom view) on top, and also somehow handle all touches outside that view.

Note that is is non-standard UI.  An actionsheet would be more HIG compliant.

Comment: Yes that one. Thanks! But the docs state that "Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices". How does the IPhone music application implements them?

Comment: forgot that you wanted this for iPhone, Have a look at the iPhone UIPopoverController implementation: WEPopover  https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

Comment: Thanks I've updated my question to reflect more accurately what I was referring to. The More button in the IPod application on the IPhone. That looks very similar to that but on the IPhone.